# How to calculate z-score from mean and standard deviation in python?

Tags: python, computational-statistics

Is there any way to calculate z-scores from given mean and standard deviation. I know how to do it by hand but couldn't able to find out how to do it in python.

The mean is 81 and standard deviation is 6.3. And I want to calculate z-scores for 93.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *[New in version 3.9.](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html)*  *[Source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/statistics.py)*

```
NormalDist(mu=81, sigma=6.3)
```

or

```
import numpy as np

def z_score(value, mean, std):
    return (value - mean) / std
```

Comment: How to use the first one. I tried this two ways but getting errors. NormalDist(mu=72, sigma=.5).zscore(93)  and statistics.NormalDist(mu=72, sigma=.5).zscore(93) . What is the right way of using it.

Comment: Check the [link](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html). What's your installed python version?

Comment: My python version is 3.7. Ok, let me try after updating my version to 3.9

Comment: Try the second one